# Temporary storage in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, session

I am making a program that would pose a question and users would be able to answer it. This is a Internet of things project and as such there will be a lot of calls to the database, which would only want to increase the value of answer A or B by one. For the record I am using PHP and Mysql and there are many unique items that would send update requests to the server.

What can I do to reduce the calls to the database?

The solution I came up with was to store somehow the data on the server, then sync the data with the database on a scheduled interval.
To update the results I would need to know only 3 things - item id, and both results. For code clarity and simplicity I made a model object with those attributes.

So far I came up with/found several ideas:

- Sessions - make session an array and just put the model objects inside it
- Create a file on the server that would store the data
- Use superglobal variables
- Create a PHP class that would have an array, in which the objects would go to and interact with the class
- Use some API - but I would be completely dependent on it working

Which one of the solutions given be the best in terms of simplicity, security and performance or is there a better way to do this whole thing?

Comment: I'd say an API is fine for this.

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to reduce calls to the database, by using a database of some kind. MySQL is going to be far more powerful than any hacked-together system.

Comment: It sounds like you might falling into premature optimizations. The most basic db installation can handle quite a lot. I have a basic service that has about 40 *concurrent* users at any time during the day, and I think only once in the last 8 months has run out of memory. This is a basic server, basic db installation, no load balancing and just a tiny layer of caching.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one database for row data and once you authorize then you can sync the data into actual database which your application needs. After sync, you can run a job of deleting unwanted data from the row database. Let me know if it works for you.